# TypeError in Python generator

Tags: typeerror

Define a generator function, *perms*, which takes in a list of numbers and a non-negative integer n. Implement the function such that it generates all permutations of length exactly n using the elements of *lst*. Assume elements of *lst* are unique, and n <= len(lst).

```py
    def perms(lst, n):
        """
        >>> g1 = perms([1,2,3],2)
        >>> print(list(g1))
        [[1,2], [1,3], [2,1], [2,3], [3,1]. [3,2]]
        """
```

Comment: You can't loop through int, also which arg you are using in your function ?

Comment: A *full* trace back would be helpful here to quickly spot *where* the error is raised exactly.

Comment: Something that you are yielding is not a list, but an int. Do a bit of debugging and you will find out what.

Comment: you can't use loop with int

Comment: yield from lst  - here u will yield int, i.e. each element of list, but everywhere else it is supposed to be list

Comment: Do not vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for Stack Exchange to distribute that content under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/). For alternatives to deletion, see: [I've thought better of my question; can I delete it?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)

Comment: The (now gradual) defacing has invalidated all current answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in line

```
yield from lst
```

Here each element of list will be yielded, which is int, and can't be used in the loop

```
for p in perms(lst, n-1)
```

The correct and working solution:

```
def perms(lst, n):
"""
>>> g1 = perms([1,2,3],2)
>>> print(list(g1))
[[1,2], [1,3], [2,1], [2,3], [3,1], [3,2]]
"""

if n == 0:
    yield []
elif n == 1:
    for elem in lst:
        yield [elem]
else:
    for p in perms(lst, n-1):
        for e in lst:
            if e not in p:
                yield p + [e]
```

Answer (score 0):

When `for p in perms(lst, n-1):` is called for the first time which is same as `for p in perms([1,2,3], 2-1)`, `perms([1,2,3], 2-1)` is not returning a list but an integer because of your `yield from lst`. `yield from lst` returns just an element from the iterable.
So `for p in perms(lst, n-1):` when called for the first time is same as `for p in 1:` which of course will throw error.